Apache: How do I allow access to my custom 403/404 error document files when IP restrictions are in force?
I have successfully set IP-based access restrictions in my Apache 2 server. However during testing with an IP address that is not allowed, my 403 custom error document fails to show because we’re blocking everything based on my IP address. Apache shows its standard 403 message instead, but with a note that it couldn’t serve the usual desired 403 custom xhtml file. It’s hardly a disaster seeing as the behaviour is correct and the UI fails gracefully. Is there a way to correct this?
I realise that I need to serve not only my "/403.htm" but also two associated .css files and an image or two. I

This is an opinion (hence the close request), but you should place all of the files in a separate directory and override the access restriction using a directory or .htaccess context.
